# Are spatial queries possible using Python and cx_Oracle?

Tags: python, oracle-spatial, cx-oracle

I am trying to execute a spatial query on an Oracle spatial table via python using the cx_Oracle package.

I can make generic queries successfully, but when I try anything involving a geometry or spatial query, it results in errors.

This is what I have tried:

```
import cx_Oracle
...

lon = -120.494352
lat = 36.585289

# open a connection to oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('myuser/mypass@spatialdb')

# create a cursor
cur = con.cursor()

# Create and populate Oracle objects
typeObj = con.gettype("MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY")
elementInfoTypeObj = con.gettype("MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY")
ordinateTypeObj = con.gettype("MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY")
obj = typeObj.newobject()
obj.SDO_GTYPE = 2001
obj.SDO_SRID = 8307
obj.SDO_ELEM_INFO = elementInfoTypeObj.newobject()
obj.SDO_ELEM_INFO.extend([1, 1, 1])
obj.SDO_ORDINATES = ordinateTypeObj.newobject()
obj.SDO_ORDINATES.extend([lon, lat])
print("Created object", obj)

# set up a distance-calculating sql statement
sql = "select id into :id from spatialtbl s where sdo_nn(s.geometry, :obj, 'sdo_num_res=1', 1) = 'TRUE'"

try:
    # execute the distance sql
    cur.execute(sql, id=id, obj=obj)
    print(f'The id is {id.getvalue()}')
except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
    print(error)
```

which results in the error:

```
ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

Can anyone tell me what I may be doing wrong code-wise or if spatial queries are even possible using Python and cx_Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "select into" was the problem (reserved for pl/sql?).

By doing the following I was able to obtain the answer:

```
# set up a distance-calculating sql statement
sql = """select id from spatialtbl s where sdo_nn(s.geometry, :ob, 'sdo_num_res=1', 1) = 'TRUE'"""

try:
    # execute the distance sql
    cur.execute(sql, ob=obj)
    id = cur.fetchone()
    print(f'The id is {id}')
except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
    print(error)
```